# How can I make my metabox appear?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, metabox

I'm fairly new to plugin development but have experience in coding. I've looked into several tutorials and managed to get my post type as slideshows, but I wanted to add a metabox to put an URL in.

However it does not show up, and the many tutorials that I followed say I should see it by now. Can somebody help? links to tutorials, code and pictures below.

tutorials followed:
https://www.sitepoint.com/real-world-example-wordpress-plugin-development/

I have also tried other tutorials (from: themefoundation and code.tutsplus) but none of them seem to work with what I have written already

(text is dutch sorry)
[image: It does not appear on here]

```
    <?php

function register_slide_content_type(){

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Slides', 'slideshow' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Slides', 'slideshow' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Nieuwe Slide', 'slideshow' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Nieuwe Slide Toevoegen', 'slideshow' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Slide', 'slideshow' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'Nieuwe Slide', 'slideshow' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'Bekijk Slide', 'slideshow' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Zoek Slides', 'slideshow' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'Geen slides gevonden', 'slideshow' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'Geen slides gevonden in prullenbak', 'slideshow' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Slide:', 'slideshow' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Slideshow', 'slideshow' ),
    );

   //arguments for post type
       $args = array(
           'labels'            => $labels,
           'hierarchical' => true,
           'description' => 'Slides voor op de website',
           'taxonomies' => array( 'plaatsen' ),
           'public'            => true,
           'publicly_queryable'=> true,
           'show_ui'           => true,
           'show_in_nav'       => true,
           'query_var'         => true,
           'supports'          => array('title','thumbnail','editor'),
           'has_archive'       => true,
           'menu_position'     => 5,
           'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
           'menu_icon'         => 'dashicons-images-alt2',
           'rewrite'            => array('slug' => 'slides', 'with_front' => 'true')
       );

    register_post_type( 'slideshow', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_slide_content_type' );

function plaatsen_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'plaatsen',
        'slideshow',
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'label' => 'Plaatsingen',
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'plaatsen',
                'with_front' => false
            )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'plaatsen_taxonomy');


add_action( 'load-post.php', 'slide_post_meta_boxes_setup' );
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', 'slide_post_meta_boxes_setup' );

function slide_post_meta_boxes_setup() {

  add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'slide_add_post_meta_boxes' );
}

function slide_add_post_meta_boxes() {
  add_meta_box(
    'pukkemukslideshow',      // Unique ID
    __( 'Slideshow', 'example' ),    // Title
    'slide_post_class_meta_box',   // Callback function
    'post_type',         // Admin page (or post type)
    'advanced',         // Context
    'high'         // Priority
  );
}


function slide_post_class_meta_box( $post ) { ?>
  <p>
    <label for="slide-post-class">Plak hier de URL waar de slide naar moet wijzen.</label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="slide-post-class" id="slide-post-class" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'slide_post_class', true ) ); ?>" size="30" />
  </p>
<?php } 

?>
```

Comment: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-wordpress-plugin another tutorial I tried but didn't help

Comment: Have you tried, when calling `add_meta_box()` to replace the `post_type` string with your actual post type, `slideshow` ?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I wasn't sure how to use that box, but now it works! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make it work because of @howdy_mcGee's comment. I did not notice that I had to call the specific post type name of it. my code is now like this and it shows up!

```
    function slide_add_post_meta_boxes() {
  add_meta_box(
    'pukkemukslideshow',      // Unique ID
    __( 'Slideshow', 'example' ),    // Title
    'slide_post_class_meta_box',   // Callback function
    'slideshow',         // Admin page (or post type)
    'advanced',         // Context
    'high'         // Priority
  );
}
```